# Setting the layout transform of image without creating a new matrixtransform

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, kinect, kinect-sdk

Ask a question
Quick access
Search related threads

I have the following code for xaml:

```
     <Grid Name="navigationGrid" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer" Grid.Row="0"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                  k:KinectRegion.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="true"

                  k:KinectRegion.IsVerticalRailEnabled="true"
                  k:KinectRegion.ZoomMode="Enabled" LayoutUpdated="scrollViewer_LayoutUpdated" >
        <Image Name="navigationImage" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
   </Grid>
```

Now I would like to change the zoom of the image manually i.e. suppose to a zoom value Z , so I do the following:

```
  System.Windows.Media.Matrix m = navigationImage.LayoutTransform.Value;
   m.ScaleAtPrepend(Z / m.M11), Z / m.M11, m.M21, m.M22);                      //Z is the zoom value
   navigationImage.LayoutTransform = new System.Windows.Media.MatrixTransform(m);
```

But after performing layoutTransform on the image, I am now not being able to use the kinect zoom gesture. I guess it is due to assigning new LayoutTransform.

So instead of

```
     new System.Windows.Media.MatrixTransform(m);
```

I would like something like

```
    navigationImage.LayoutTransform.SetValue(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, Z / m.M11);
```

but this gives me an error "Cannot set a property on object 'Identity' because it is in a read-only state."  So my question is how to set new value to layoutTransform.

Comment: I can't really speak to the kinect-gesture side of this issue... but LayoutTransforms are sealed and cannot be dynamically altered. (Look at the isSelaed property during runtime, you will see it is 'true'). The proper way to dynamically change them is to instantiate a new one, as you do in your code. Whether that would have an effect on the gestures, I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0):

You set Scale Transform to Layout Transform and then update the Scale Transform.

```
var scale = new ScaleTransform();
navigationImage.LayoutTransform = scale;

// Elsewhere...
scale.ScaleX = newValue;
```